# Multiple icons for one package? Android - Eclipse development

Tags: eclipse

I am learning how to develop for Android slowly.  I noticed that when I go to Applications on the emulator or on my actual phone that there are multiple icons all for my one app.

Does anyone know know how to stop this or why its there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the manifest setup for every class like below:  Not correct... I still haven't figured out why the manifest file is there, but know this was the problem.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />



    </intent-filter>
```